# Isn't Using the basename function with $_FILES['userFile']['name'] Redundant?

Tags: php, file, file-upload

According to [the *POST method uploads* section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) of [the PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php), `$_FILES['userfile']['name']` is the original name of the file on the client machine. Example #2 in that section uses the [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function with `$_FILES['userfile']['name']` like the following:

```
$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
```

I did some experiments on my local host (*Apache 2.2.14, PHP 5.3.1, Windows XP*) and found out that the following two lines are equivalent:

```
$_FILES['userFile']['name'];            // "file.txt"
basename($_FILES['userFile']['name']);  // "file.txt"
```

That is, using the `basename` function with `$_FILES['userFile']['name']` seems rather redundant. Isn't it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> That is, using the basename function with $_FILES['userFile']['name']  seems rather redundant. Isn't it?

No, first and foremost for security reasons as @Gumbo describes in his answer; secondly, because older versions of IE used to deliver the full path of the file on client side, like

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Username\Desktop\Image_cropped.jpg
```

that behaviour stopped as recently as IE8. From [**this MSDN blog entry**](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection.aspx) discovered via [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130560/get-full-path-of-a-file-with-fileupload-control):

> **File Upload control**
>
> Additionally, the “Include local directory path when uploading files” URLAction has been set to "Disable" for the Internet Zone. This change prevents leakage of potentially sensitive local file-system information to the Internet. For instance, rather than submitting the full path C:\users\ericlaw\documents\secret\image.png, Internet Explorer 8 will now submit only the filename image.png.

Comment: @Gordon cheers. @Gumbo Re the leakage: true, but it was awfully useful in Content Management Systems to save the original location of an uploaded resource. I really miss that feature. Good to know that it can be reactivated using the zone model.

Answer (score 6):

HTTP requests can be forged and thus the filename provided in the header can also be manipulated.

If you want to ensure that only a filename is given, validate the value or filter it with `basename` to just get the filename.

Comment: Yup, this is the most important reason for `basename()` here.

Comment: For example, you can receive `../../../etc/passwd` so, without basename, you'd end up with `/var/www/uploads/../../../etc/passwd` == `/etc/passwd`

Answer (score 0):

using basename() on a full path eg `/path/mydir/file.txt`, returns you `file.txt`. Its useful when you have a full path to parse and you just want to get the last part of the path.