# how to print a selected photo name from input type

Tags: php, file-upload

Can anyone tell me, how I can print a photo name? The photo will be selected from input `type=file`.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
$photo = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
//$photo_name = basename($photo);
echo $photo;
```

This code doesn't show actual file name. It print as like this (`php3515.tmp`);

Comment: `echo $_FILES['photo']['name']`. RTM:  http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Isn't Using the basename function with $\_FILES\['userFile'\]\['name'\] Redundant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347056/isnt-using-the-basename-function-with-filesuserfilename-redundant)  The question itself answers this very basic question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Print the file `name` instead of `tmpname`

Try this:

```
echo $_FILES['photo']['name'];
```

Answer (score 2):

`php3515.tmp` in your case is a temporary file generated by PHP. You have to move this file to your desired location with `move_uploaded_file()` function, which takes your `$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']` as first argument, and path and new filename as second argument.

Here is an example taken from [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

```
$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}

echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";
```

Note `$_FILES['userfile']['name']` in this example, which contains the original file name.

Comment: This doesn't even answer the OP's question, which simply was _"how can i print a photo name"_.

Comment: @Magnus Yes, my mistake. I already edited the answer to highlight the `name` index in `$_FILES` array. I leave the answer here as it could provide more useful information about file upload in PHP. Especially the `print_r($_FILES);` line would be priceless for education reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know, that [you have 5 parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) in `$_FILES['userfile']`:

- **name** - original name of uploaded file
- **tmp_name** - system name that is physically writen on disk by system
- **size** - size of file
- **error** - code of error - 0 mean no problem
- **type** - type of saved file

If you want you original name, to display, use simply:

```
$_FILES['userfile']['name']
```

You also have function [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), that allows you to safely move the file from a temporary place to your own. Another way, after the end of PHP process, you uploaded file will be deleted.

```
$path = __DIR__  . '/upload/' . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $path);
```

`$result` show you, is system correctly save a file in given place.