# Get the full path from a file upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

When I'm using the file upload control I just get only the file name, but I want to get the full path of the file location.

How do I get the full path from the file upload control in ASP.NET?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get full path of a file with FileUpload Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130560/get-full-path-of-a-file-with-fileupload-control)

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible in any browser, as a security measure.

If this were possible, an attacker could gain information regarding how files/folders were structured on a client computer.

Why do you need this information?

Comment: ´UploadControl.PostedFile.FileName´ gives the complete path in internet explorer 8, (at least in my tests) Chrome does not.

Comment: @Magnus - IE8 is broken that way.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get it because the browser does not send it. It would be dangerous if the browsers sent the full path at user's system.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ASP.NET upload control, on client side you can get the full path like the following.

```
   document.getElementById('UploadControl').value
```

On the server side,

```
  UploadControl.PostedFile.FileName
```

Check the MSDN article *[HttpPostedFile.FileName Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.filename%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)* for more information.

Answer (score -2):

I think you got file path of the upload control

```
HttpPostedFile httpBrowseFile = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
int FileLength = httpBrowseFile.ContentLength;
byte[] myData = new byte[FileLength];

httpBrowseFile.InputStream.Read(myData, 0, FileLength);
FName = path + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName.Substring(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
```