# How to get entire file path of telerik RadUpload control in asp textbox at client side

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am using RadUpload control of telerik.
I have added Rad upload on page and one asp Text box. what I want to do is **OnClientFileSelected** event selected file path get added in asp Text box at client side. I did tried following ways but i got only file name i.e. test.text or test.doc. I do want to add entire path in asp text box like "C:\folder1\folder2\test1.txt". How should i do this.

```
function fileSelected(radUpload, eventArgs)
 { 
   var input = eventArgs.get_fileInputField().value;
   document.getElementById("<%= txtPath.ClientID %>").value=input;
 }
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get full path of a file with FileUpload Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130560/get-full-path-of-a-file-with-fileupload-control)

Comment: For numerous security reasons you cannot get the full client path of the file for upload.  now, depending on version of the browser, older browsers might put that path in.  Ultimately the world has felt that this information is too dangerous and of little to no value to the server.

Comment: @Chris, you mean little or no value to the Client.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring: No, I meant the full path of where the file came from is of little value to the server.  All it should care about is the file itself.  Where it lived on the client machine should be of no use legitimate use.  BTW, I upvoted you..

Comment: ah I see. I thought you meant that the file path on the server is of no value to the client machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it client side without a little extra help since the client has next to no information about the server. Try setting a hidden field from the server side to store the file path.

```
 HiddenField1.Value = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/my_upload_directory/")
```

Then on the client side, you just concatonate the `HiddenField1.value` and the `txtPath.value`

```
var fullPath = document.getElementById("<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>").value + document.getElementById("<%= txtPath.ClientID %>").value;
```

Comment: Chris is is correct it depend up on the version of browser. IE8 gives me full path but Firefox does not. Thanks for your help