# asp:FileUpload fetch the file Path

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

VS 2008

How to fetch the Full File path for the File Uploaded in asp.net ??

Either HTML or ASP.Net Server Control, i need to use File Upload - Browse feature and need to fetch the Complete file path.

My guess is Due to security reasons, ASP.Net does not support asp:FileUpload to deliver the Full File Path ..!

What would be the best way to get the file path ?

Comment: I guess Answer is in your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what you want by design (at least on modern browsers).  This would be a security issue if you could.

You can read more about this [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection.aspx).

Snipit:

> Historically, the HTML File Upload
>   Control () has been
>   the source of a significant number of
>   information disclosure
>   vulnerabilities. To resolve these
>   issues, two changes were made to the
>   behavior of the control.
>
> To block attacks that rely on
>   “stealing” keystrokes to
>   surreptitiously trick the user into
>   typing a local file path into the
>   control, the File Path edit box is now
>   read-only. The user must explicitly
>   select a file for upload using the
>   File Browse dialog.
>
> IE8 read-only File Path box
>
> Additionally, the “Include local
>   directory path when uploading files”
>   URLAction has been set to "Disable"
>   for the Internet Zone. This change
>   prevents leakage of potentially
>   sensitive local file-system
>   information to the Internet. For
>   instance, rather than submitting the
>   full path
>   C:\users\ericlaw\documents\secret\image.png,
>   Internet Explorer 8 will now submit
>   only the filename image.png.

Comment: igot the answer .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130560/get-full-path-of-a-file-with-fileupload-control