# How to get the path of a file which is in file upload control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get full path of a file with FileUpload Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130560/get-full-path-of-a-file-with-fileupload-control)

I want to get the path of a file when we select the file in file upload control.

eg. if my file is placed at `C:\Documents and Settings\example.txt`

when I browse it by using file upload control then how I will get this `C:\Documents and Settings\example.txt` path.

Comment: You can't get the client path; only the filename. This is by design from what I remember, a security feature. Note this is not true for all browsers though - see http://codeblog.shawson.co.uk/fileupload-postedfile-filename-includes-all-the-client-path-info-but-only-in-ie/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, for security reason, you can get the fileName.

Use FileName property of the FileUploadControl

```
FileUploadControl.FileName
```

Read this blog: http://weblogs.asp.net/ashicmahtab/archive/2009/05/20/fileupload-control-doesn-t-give-full-path-help.aspx

Comment: habib i think you are right man.

Comment: @RajbirSingh, It depends on browser, check the blog post.

Answer (score 3):

***[Googling ASP.NET Upload Control yielded this as the first result](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/):***

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(FileUploadControl.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
            FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT -** Now understanding your question fully, this is actually a question that has already been asked. Take a look at ***[Get full path of a file with FileUpload Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130560/get-full-path-of-a-file-with-fileupload-control)*** and look at the highest upvoted answer.

Comment: Hey scott i know how to upload the file. But i do not know how to get the path which is this "C:\Documents and Settings\example.txt" from where the file is upload.

Comment: Your are talking about how to get the name of the file. This "string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);" will give just file name not this ""C:\Documents and Settings\example.txt" path.

Comment: Right, right, right. I misunderstood what you were trying to get. You can't get the client's path for privacy reasons. You just get the filename.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the browser and OS your client is using, there may be no way for you to get the whole path - it's entirely up to what the browser supplies you.

[According to this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filename.aspx) (see the bottom), IE on Windows XP gives the whole path, but on Windows 7 only gives the filename.

Only giving the filename is the expected behaviour.