# AjaxFileUpload fileName is full path, not just file name

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I run a local version of my Web Form in visual studio 2010 with the Ajax File Upload control.

I test by uploading a file and writing the `e.fileName`, `e.fileSize`, etc. to a database, and then using a `GridView` to download the file later.

My issue is this: when I write the `e.fileName` to the database, it gives me the entire path of the file (i.e. "C:\Folder\filename.xls") as the files name.

Advice on correcting this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in `System.IO`:

```
string justTheName = Path.GetFileName(e.fileName);
```

And then pass "justTheName" to the database.

Comment: I had made this change, and it works great! This seems to apply just for writing on the database from a local build/debug of my code. The problem persists when I put this code on the IIS in its virtual folder (i.e. the file name is still 'C:\folder\filename.xls') Thanks for your response but the issue is no longer on my local build but is still being applied when it runs from the server build.

Comment: @central Ah, good catch.  According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130560/get-full-path-of-a-file-with-fileupload-control/3077008#3077008), it might be more beneficial (in your development environment) to use `Server.MapPath` to get the real path, then use `Path.GetFileName`.  Something like `string justTheName = Path.GetFileName(Server.MapPath(e.fileName));`