# fileupload C# get the exact path given

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, file-upload

I use asp.net with c# with webforms.

I have a fileupload control and i need to grab the exact path chosen by user.

I tried Server.MapPath and Path.GetFullPath and everything but this would give me the full path like c:\files\dbg.......

If the user chooses \ServerT\files\nathan.txt i need this exact text: "\ServerT\files\nathan.txt"...

it looks like c# doesnt allow this from what i've seen so far, but is there a way like capturing the text there with jquery and put it in a hidden field that has a runat="server" attribute and then retrieve the value from the code behind ?

bottom line: if the user chooses \ServerT\files\nathan.txt i need the exact string "\ServerT\files\nathan.txt"...

Comment: there is NO WAY to retrieve the full path from HTML file input element ... for security reasons

Comment: No way to get this info. See for yourself:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/1130801/2191976

Comment: HTML file inputs pass only the filename, not the full path, for security reasons. You can't do what you're trying to do.