# Spring MVC get full file path during file upload

Tags: spring-mvc, file-upload

Am using spring mvc and working on file upload. I get the file name successfully passed to my controller and it is of type MultiPartFile. But it is returning only the file name. But i need the path of the file also. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

From Spring documentation.

"MultipartFile.getOriginalFilename()

This may contain path information depending on the browser used, but it typically will not with any other than Opera."

However what you are asking could be a security concern as you can get file system info in full path beside browser don't generally pass this information. check answer by craigd  and others in another question [1130560](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130560/get-full-path-of-a-file-with-fileupload-control)