# Asp.Net C# Getting Full Path of a File

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, file-upload, path

I am building a web application using WCF. I need to full path of a file to open and  upload it to web service. 
What I am doing is first opening a file by its full path, then take stream of it and finally upload it to service. My code is below

```
string Path = Server.MapPath( FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

System.IO.Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(@Path);
```

I can't get full path of the file for security reasons.

How can I read the file that users select?

Comment: Use `FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream` or `byte[] FileUpload1.FileBytes`  or `Stream FileUpload1.FileContent` properties.

Comment: @AVD Thank you so much, it works!

Answer (score 2):

`Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName)` is the path to a file on the server. You cannot get the full path of the client machine of the file Using the `FileUpload`.

Comment: You cannot get the client's full file path and you don't need it.

Comment: It should be noted that to access `Server` you need to use the library `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the full client path to access it. You can use the FileBytes
property in order to read the contents of uploaded file.

Comment: How can I do that? @saritas

Answer (score 0):

As others have already suggested there's no reason you need the file path to the client in order to save a file on your server. In the case you need some clearer explanation for this, then please refer to these answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3077008/2196675

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1130718/2196675