# how to store a full path of fileupload?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I need to store the full path of file upload so that I can retrieve to display in another project. currently it only stores the name of the file that I upload. How can I change it so that it will store the full path?

```
protected void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string EventName = lbl_eventname.Text;
    string FeedbackDesc = tb_description.Text;
    int FeedbackRating = Rating1.CurrentRating;
    string Image;
    string fileName = "";
    string desc = tb_description.Text;

    BLL_feedback insert = new BLL_feedback();
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile) {
        Image = "image/" + FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/image/" + FileUpload1.FileName));
        DAL_Feedback feedback = new DAL_Feedback();
        int result = 0;
        result = feedback.Insert(FeedbackDesc, FeedbackRating, fileName, EventName);
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Feedback submitted!');</script>");
    }
}
```

This is how I insert into the database:

```
    public int Insert (string desc, int rating, string image, string eventName)
    {
        StringBuilder sql;
        SqlCommand sqlCmd;
        int result = 0;

        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HotelDB"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

        string strCommandText = "INSERT Feedback(FeedbackDesc, FeedbackRating, Image, EventName)";
        strCommandText += "Values(@FeedbackDesc, @FeedbackRating, @Image, @EventName)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FeedbackDesc", desc);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FeedbackRating", rating);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", image);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventName", eventName);

        myConnect.Open();
        result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnect.Close();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Did u tested in IE? If yes did u tried Chrome?Pls share FileUpload1 implementation or source lib

Comment: Tested in both IE and chrome but didn't work

Comment: What path do you want? The client's or the created at the server's?

Comment: the client's path

Comment: take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130560/get-full-path-of-a-file-with-fileupload-control

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get full path of a file with FileUpload Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130560/get-full-path-of-a-file-with-fileupload-control)

Comment: You cannot get the client path. It's a security thing.

Comment: Ohh I see... Thanks for the help